# How to create a Nuget Package for Xamarin Forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Recently I have started working on Xamarin and I have created a UI component which I can use across multiple projects. I have created Entry component for Xamarin.Forms and added my own customisation for iOS and android.

Now I want to create a Nuget Package which I can directly download from Nuget store for other projects. I'm looking for proper steps for creating a Nuget Package based on my xamarin solution. But unfortunately I'm not getting proper steps which I can follow to create this.

All kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Get Release build of all projects inside your project(that will be in nuget package)
2. Download & run Nuget Package Explorer
3. **Create a new Package**
4. Right click to **Package Conext** and add **lib** into there
5. Regarding your supported platform (UWP, iOS, Android, PCL) add folders below and drag& drops DLL's you've been created before.

[image: Nuget folders]

6. Export package form **File->Publish**

**Note:** You can open & check any Nuget package content via **Nuget Package Explorer** that might gives you some hints.

Comment: Can we do this only from widows with Visual Studio? can we do it on MAC with Xamarin studio?

Comment: **Nuget Package Explorer** does not have a Mac application.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but for the folks that land here like me, this has been smoothed a bit.

It is explained in : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/single-codebase/

Basically you can do it more GUI oriented in Xamarin Studio.

There is an option like this now in Xamarin Studio

[image]